Is there a way to improve the memory allocations of Spring PathPattern request URI matchings?
we are using Spring as our backend server.
we started doing some performance testing on our server and did some investigation regarding the memory allocations of the server during high load.
basically we have 1 API which is called a lot.
we saw that the memory allocations arriving from the code to handle the path pattern matching takes a lot of memory (10+GB )
We already refactored our service to move from Ant to PathPatternMatcher using
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: path_pattern_parser

but, unfortunately we didn't see improvement.
when loaded the JFR to Intellij memory profilling we saw that most of the memory allocations are arriving from org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPattern.MatchingContext in line
org.springframework/spring-web/6.1.6/be78ef476d499275ce288edac95b9ec512d5164f/spring-web-6.1.6-sources.jar!/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.java:216
is there a way we can configure/improve someway the spring path pattern matching to reduce the memory allocations?


Which version are you on? Have you tried upgrading?

Additionally why is this a problem? Apparently you have enough memory and as the graph shows (at least what I see) is that when it reaches the peak it does a GC and memory gets freed again.

we are using Spring boot version 3.2.5

@M.Deinum , you are right that when it reaches a peak , GC kicks in and the memory is getting freed. however, during the peak , the memory pressure is high which means is a limit for us considering the load of the application and the pod resources. if the memory usage will be lower , we would have been able to do more load on the pod with the same amount of resources (looking for cost optimization and reducing our memory usage)
